# Android java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial:

Tags: android-studio, exception, manifest

This is the log containing the error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-202
Process: org.cade.codigos, PID: 2798
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.browser.provider.BrowserProvider2 from ProcessRecord{f90b843 2798:org.cade.codigos/u0a57} (pid=2798, uid=10057) 
requires com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS 
or com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3550)
at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2018)
at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1468)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:475)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
at org.cade.codigos.providers.BookmarksProviderWrapper.updateHistory(BookmarksProviderWrapper.java:370)
at org.cade.codigos.ui.runnables.HistoryUpdater.run(HistoryUpdater.java:53)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Worth noting this exception raised when trying Nexus 5 (Android 6.0,Api 23 ), Nexus S Api 22 Lollipop is working.

This is the whole Manifest, Currently I am only using .codigos.ui.activities.RequestDataForm and .codigos.ui.activities.MainActivity

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
   CADE Browser for Android

   Copyright (C) 2014
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.cade"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="13"
    android:versionName="1">
    android:versionName="CADE Codigos" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16"
       />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.cade.codigos.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.Application"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="CADE Códigos" >

        <!-- android:debuggable="false" -->

        <activity
            android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.RequestDataForm"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="CADE Códigos">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/AboutActivity.Title"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.EditBookmarkActivity"
            android:label="@string/EditBookmarkActivity.Title"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.BookmarksListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.HistoryListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.DownloadsListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.AdBlockerWhiteListActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.BookmarksHistoryActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity
            android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.ChangelogActivity"
            android:label="@string/ChangelogActivity.Title"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.preferences.PreferencesActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.preferences.HomepagePreferenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/HomepagePreferenceActivity.Title"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.preferences.SearchUrlPreferenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/SearchUrlPreferenceActivity.Title"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.preferences.UserAgentPreferenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/UserAgentPreferenceActivity.Title"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
        <activity android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.MobileViewListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.WeaveBookmarksListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.preferences.WeavePreferencesActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.preferences.WeaveServerPreferenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/WeaveServerPreferenceActivity.Title"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />

        <provider
            android:name=".codigos.providers.ZircoBookmarksContentProvider"
            android:authorities="org.cade.codigos.providers.zircobookmarkscontentprovider" />
        <provider
            android:name=".codigos.providers.WeaveContentProvider"
            android:authorities="org.cade.codigos.providers.weavecontentprovider" />

        <receiver android:name=".codigos.utils.ProxyChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROXY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.Splashscreen"
            android:label="CADE App">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
                android:name=".codigos.ui.activities.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="CADE Codigos" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver
            android:name="org.cade.codigos.ui.activities.Receiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="org.cade.codigos" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```